# How to add React Native to my app? (Android)

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am currently doing some research comparing a full `react-native app` with an `android/iOS native + react-native app`. It would be interesting, from a company's perspective, to see how much we could increase the amount of value produced with this approach.

My question is, how can we inflate, for example, a react-native form inside an android native fragment or activity.

I was hoping, that way, the android/iOS native developers would only focus on the appropriate menus for their respective OS, and the forms and so to be made in `react-native`.

I followed this official documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps

In this example I tried to inflate the React-Native code on the `MyReactActivity.java` class.

**MyReactActivity.java**

```
public class MyReactActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DefaultHardwareBackBtnHandler {
private ReactRootView mReactRootView;
private ReactInstanceManager mReactInstanceManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mReactRootView = new ReactRootView(this);
    mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
            .setApplication(getApplication())
            .setBundleAssetName("index.android.bundle")
            .setJSMainModulePath("index")
            .addPackage(new MainReactPackage())
            .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
            .build();
    mReactRootView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, "myreactnativeapp", null);
    setContentView(mReactRootView);
}

@Override
public void invokeDefaultOnBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (mReactInstanceManager != null) {
        mReactInstanceManager.onHostPause(this);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (mReactInstanceManager != null) {
        mReactInstanceManager.onHostResume(this, this);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if (mReactInstanceManager != null) {
        mReactInstanceManager.onHostDestroy(this);
    }
    if (mReactRootView != null) {
        mReactRootView.unmountReactApplication();
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mReactInstanceManager != null) {
        mReactInstanceManager.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU && mReactInstanceManager != null) {
        mReactInstanceManager.showDevOptionsDialog();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private final int OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                    Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
            startActivityForResult(intent, OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE);
        }
    }

    Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyReactActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

**Output** (after running `yarn start` on the console)

**MainActivity**
[image: MainActivity]

**MyReactctivity**
[image: MyReactctivity]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi , Welcome to SO . Please share some code as to what you have done till now. The community will then be able to help you out. Thanks